# Multiplication inverse relationships and correlations with $n$

Tags: abstract-algebra

a). When looking at a non-zero element $c$ $\in \mathbb Z_n$ that contains inverses, what is it's relationship with $n$?

b). Also, looking at a non-zero element $c$ $\in \mathbb Z_n$ that does not contains inverses, what is it's relationship with $n$?

I know it has something to do with prime numbers and factorization.

Any help would be delightful.

EDIT: After looking at it, is it true that a). $gcd(z,n) = 1$

b). $gcd(z,n) > 1$

Comment: If $c$ and $n$ are coprime, $c$ is a unit, or namely it has an inverse. If they are not coprime, $c$ is a zero-divisor, or namely there is $d$ such that $cd=0$ and thus it has no inverse.

Comment: a) if the inverse of $c $ is $k $ then that means $ck=1+mn $ for some integer $m$. When is that possible. B) $ck=1+mn $ *doesn't* have solutions. When is that *im*possible. Hint: it starts with "B" and rhymes with "kazoo".